# Read more link to external webpage

Tags: links, read-more

is it possible for the "Read More" buttons in front page which normally leads to the post , to change it to lead to an external webpage. So one can lead to post and the other can lead to external webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Read More filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_The_Read_More_Link_Text

Per the discussion below, in this case, there's a plugin called Page Links To that may solve your problem. You would create a post in WP but set its permalink to the external URL you want to link to, so it would appear on the front page but its read more button would go to the external URL for just that post (or however many others you created this way).

Comment: yes but this changes all the Read More buttons not only one. Right?

Comment: @AggelosSunDanceTroulakis within the func you hook to [the_content_more_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content_more_link/) you can access the `global $post` to decide what URL you want to link to.

Comment: If you only want to change the front page (not other locations where Read More may appear, like categories and other archives), you could edit `front-page.php` directly with a custom loop.

Comment: I mean in the front page I have 3 "Read more" buttons for 3 different posts. I need only one of them to point to external page

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, there's a plugin called Page Links To that may solve your problem. You would create a post in WP but set its permalink to the external URL you want to link to, so it would appear on the front page but its read more button would go to the external URL for just that post (or however many others you created this way).

Comment: oh! at last! thank you! if you want add it as answer :)

Comment: For completeness sake, the way in which you'd actually accomplish this using a `the_content_more_link` filter would be to use a custom field (post metadata) to set the external link. In the filter, check for the existence of that meta-data, and if it exists return anchor markup containing the meta-value (the external URL) - if the post doesn't have the meta-data, return the argument passed into the filter as-is. This leaves permalinks untouched, however - you should additionally use a `pre_get_posts` hook to `wp_redirect()` queries for single posts with the meta-data to the external URL.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is put custom meta field, for example Advanced custom field, create text or link field, then you can output read more link in your template, loop or singe like this:

```
<?php if (get_field('custom_link')): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('custom_link'); ?>" target="_blank">Read more</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```